# Center image when in mobile version

Tags: html, css, sass

[this is how it looks on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSiCx.png)

I have an image that has the full width of the screen width: 100%;

Specifically this image is a map, in the whole center of the map there is a "path", with the points that when clicking, some manners appear,

The problem is that I don't know how to make that huge sensitive map so that it can be seen well on different devices, what I was thinking is what an overflow is but I really don't know how to do it so only the left part of the image is shown

This is the code:

```
.map-container {
    padding: 3.2rem .8rem;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: $blue;
}

.img-map {
    width: 100%;
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="map-container">
            <img class="img-map" src="public/images/mapa.svg">
            <div id="step1" class="point argentina"></div>
            <div id="step2" class="point brasil"></div>
            <div id="step3" class="point venezuela"></div>
            <div id="step4" class="point colombia"></div>
            <div id="step5" class="point panama"></div>
            <div id="step6" class="point mexico"></div>
            <div class="mod-paso-1">
                <div class="mod-info">
                    <p><b>XXXXXXXXXX</b></p>
                    <p><b>XXXXXXXXX</b></p>
                    <p><b>XXXXXXXX</b></p>
                    <P>XXXXX</P>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You who recommend me to make this map responsive?

"-Cut the image for each resolution?"

If you need more details, I am attentive

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to use `width: 100vw;`?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of how it currently displays on your screen?

Answer (score 0):

Add 100% width to your map container so the image width can take 100% of the screen whether on desktop or mobile:

```
.map-container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3.2rem .8rem;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: The map has it with this class ".img-map"

Comment: Yes, but the map is inside the map-container so its 100% will be 100% of the container, so if you want it to be 100% of the screen, the map-container width must be 100%. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

May be this would help you

```
.img-map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried to fiddle around a bit with this issue.
you will have to open on mobile view because I only focused on that for now.

```
Here is the codepen
https://codepen.io/Spoochy/pen/LYYQzPv
```

I combined object-fit:cover and viewport heights

However, object-fit is quite new (as far as I know) and might not be fully compatible for all browsers. so I would suggest to always check the **Can I use Tables** before using unknown properties.

https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit